# Re-focus after click outside md-chips

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

After upgrading the Angular Material from version 1.1.1 to 1.1.4, the md-chips are not working as before.

Type a string in the entry and then click outside, the focus returns to the input.

I do not want this to happen.

With Angular Material 1.1.1:

https://youtu.be/LD2CxbuMxJg

With Angular Material 1.1.4:

https://youtu.be/dG1kKvU1Y0s

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce this. What browser are you using?

Comment: Live example of [Angular Material 1.1.4](https://fiddle.jshell.net/nxvp1mdu/3/) and [Angular Material 1.1.1](https://fiddle.jshell.net/c1osj4p7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In `mdChipsCtrl` there is a boolean variable responsible for returning focus to the entry called `shouldFocusLastChip`.

I overwritten the function by changing the value of this variable with the following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('mdChips', function () {
  return {                                                                   
    restrict: 'E',                                                          
    require: 'mdChips', // Extends the original mdChips directive           
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, mdChipsCtrl) {              
      mdChipsCtrl.appendChip = function (newChip) {
        // Set to FALSE                                  
        this.shouldFocusLastChip = false;                                                                    

        if (this.useTransformChip && this.transformChip) {                  
          var transformedChip = this.transformChip({'$chip': newChip});     

          // Check to make sure the chip is defined before assigning it, otherwise, we'll just assume
          // they want the string version.                                  
          if (angular.isDefined(transformedChip)) {                         
            newChip = transformedChip;                                      
          }                                                                 
        }                                                                   

        // If items contains an identical object to newChip, do not append  
        if (angular.isObject(newChip)){                                     
          var identical = this.items.some(function(item){                   
            return angular.equals(newChip, item);                           
          });                                                               
          if (identical) return;                                            
        }                                                                   

        // Check for a null (but not undefined), or existing chip and cancel appending
        if (newChip === null || this.items.indexOf(newChip) + 1) return;    

        // Append the new chip onto our list                                
        var length = this.items.push(newChip);                              
        var index = length - 1;                                             

        // Update model validation                                          
        this.ngModelCtrl.$setDirty();                                       
        this.validateModel();                                               

        // If they provide the md-on-add attribute, notify them of the chip addition
        if (this.useOnAdd && this.onAdd) {                                  
          this.onAdd({ '$chip': newChip, '$index': index });                
        }                                                                   
      };                                                                    
    }                                                                       
};
```